# fstream.open() set failbit

Tags: c++, unix, std

I've a problem accessing a file with fstream.
Here is the code

```
 Conf::Conf()
{
  log = Log::Instance();
  _db_user = "";
  _db_password = "";
  _db_tableName = "";

  _treat["db:user"] = &Conf::set_db_user;
  _treat["db:adress"] = &Conf::set_db_adress;
  _treat["db:password"] = &Conf::set_db_password;
  _treat["db:tableName"] = &Conf::set_db_tableName;
  _treat["broadcast:adress"] = &Conf::set_broadcast_adress;

  _file.open("/home/borne/BorneApp/borne.conf", std::fstream::in);
  if (!_file.is_open())
    log->logThis("Error while opening borne.conf", "[INIT]", Log::ERROR);
}


void Conf::extract()
{
  std::string tmp = "";

  while (std::getline(_file, tmp))
  {
   if (_treat.find(tmp.substr(0, tmp.find("="))) != _treat.end())
    callMember(this, _treat[tmp.substr(0, tmp.find("="))])(tmp);
   else
     log->logThis("Parse Error in your configuration file", "[CONF]", Log::WARNING);
   }

}
```

getline return me nothing

So i have check if i have some error and...
_file.fail() is set to TRUE

Facts : file is open properly.
I launch the program from /home/borne/BorneApp/ 
when i change this

```
_file.open("/home/borne/BorneApp/borne.conf", std::fstream::in);
```

to this :

```
_file.open("./borne.conf", std::fstream::in);
```

Everything works fine.

I don't uderstan why i've got that fail bit, can you help me?

Comment: What happens if you print the file using `cat /home/borne/BorneApp/borne.conf` from the command line?

Comment: i've got the file content printed(it exist, it's the good path)

Comment: I fear the issue is in the code you hide from us.  Could you give us a minimal but complete example reproducing the problem?

Comment: @AProgrammer i've edited the main post. This is where I use the _file.
I call the Conf constructor then the extract method. Everything work fine with "./borne.conf"

Comment: @ThomasGrockowiak, I was asking for something along [this line](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ie where we could reproduce your problem (I think that it will be one of those time when while trying to build one understand the issue alone and then see that it wasn't related to the asked question; your code already excluded one of the possible root cause which would have occured with a char* as tmp )

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, `_file.is_open()` and `_file.fail()` both return `true`.

My guess is that the `fstream` is already associated with a file (i.e you already called `open` on it for some reason).

If the stream is already associated with a file, calling `open` on it fails.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::fstream fs;
  fs.open("test.txt", std::fstream::in);
  if(!fs.is_open())
    std::cout << "Not opened" << std::endl;
  if(fs.fail())
    std::cout << "Failed" << std::endl;
  fs.open("test2.txt", std::fstream::in);
  if(!fs.is_open())
    std::cout << "[2] Not opened" << std::endl;
  if(fs.fail())
    std::cout << "[2] Failed" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Running it prints `[2] Failed`, which corresponds to what you describe. If the file couldn't be opened, `_file.is_open()` would reply `false` as this example shows when `test.txt` is suppressed or read permissions are removed from it.

So something in your code is probably making `open` being called twice. Is it called somewhere else than in the constructor of `Conf` in your code ?